# How to access a member of an stdClass in PHP that starts with an @

Tags: php, arrays, json, stdclass

I have some json object that I decoded, and one of the attributes starts with an "@" and I can't access the element with php because it throws an error.

```
                    [offers] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [id] => levaka0B8a
                            )
                    )
```

How would I go about accessing attributes?

Comment: This rather looks like it was some weird conversion from a SimpleXmlElement to a StdClass. Can you please clarify how you got the dump?

Comment: this is conversion from JSON not XML :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can access it by a string:

```
echo $obj->{'@attributes'}->id; // levaka0B8a
```

Or a variable:

```
$name = '@attributes';
echo $obj->$name->id;
```

For more information on how variables are defined and used, see the following docs:

- [Variable Basics](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php) - Useful for learning what can be accessed as a variable without needing to use strings.
- [Variable Variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) - How we used the variable to act as the name for another variable.  This can be dangerous so tread carefully

Answer (score 9):

You could do this:

```
$object->{'@attributes'}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to use,

```
$objSimpleXml->attributes()->id
```

Sample Code to Refer

```
<?php
$string = <<<XML
<a>
 <foo name="one" game="lonely">1</foo>
</a>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
var_dump( $xml );
foreach($xml->foo[0]->attributes() as $a => $b) {
    echo $a,'="',$b,"\"\n";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

direct access is below from ircmaxwell or Richard Tuin, however you can decode JSON with second param true and recive array insted what could be an easier to access