# Access an object member inside an array of objects using Twig Engine

Tags: php, arrays, symfony

I have array of object if I using `print_r` looks like :

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => User1
                [user_id] => 1
                [email] => user1@website.com
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => User2
                [user_id] => 2
                [email] => user2@website.com
            )

        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => User3
                [user_id] => 3
                [email] => user3@website.com
            )
     )
```

I want to loop and show them using `Twig Engine` then access member of object like `name`, `email` using `Twig Engine` too. How do that? I was tried but always error. I'm new about Twig.

Comment: what did you tried??

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI I want to access member of object like `name` or `email` or `user_id`. I want to show them as html like `<li>`. And also with these value I will use one of them for another proses.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access a member of an stdClass in PHP that starts with an @](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660291/how-to-access-a-member-of-an-stdclass-in-php-that-starts-with-an)

Comment: @UgyAstro if you would include at least some code showing HOW you try to access them, it would be easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in Twig

```
{% for user in users %}
    <li><span>{{ user.name }}</span><span>{{ user.email}}</span></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

$object = your Std class Object;

```
foreach($object as $data)
{
    echo $data->name;
    echo $data->user_id;
    echo $data->email;
}
```

In `twig` you can use it like:

```
{% for user in users %}
    <li><span>{{ user.name }}</span><span>{{ user.email}}</span></li>
{% endfor %}
```